# Terminating queries using psycopg2 not working

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I can use `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(some_pid)` in the PSequel GUI and it works great.

With the same credentials I try:

```
conn = connect(dbname=...etc,)
cursor = self.connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT pg_terminate_backend({});'.format(pid))
conn.commit()
```

In psycopg2, but it doesn't work. Why could this be?

Is there a different type of cursor commit?

Comment: "it doesn't work" - could you please elaborate? Any errors? How are you getting the `pid`? Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting the `pid` from pg_stat_activity.

Comment: try `cursor.execute('SELECT pg_terminate_backend(%s);',(pid))`?..